# SQL: Query for date greater than X months and Y days ago

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to construct a SQL query for MySQL that can `SELECT` based on a date being greater than 1 month and 4 days ago?

I know that the following is possible:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE DATE_COL > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

However, what if I wanted to add another 4 days (or any number of days for that matter) to the interval in the date_sub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to wrap it:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL 
WHERE DATE_COL > date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a nested  date_sub

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM TBL 
  WHERE DATE_COL > date_sub(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```